# Problema com entrada de mais de um número inteiro com input

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

Estou com problema para captar a entrada de mais de um número inteiro em um só input.

Ex:

```
numero = int(input('Digite o primeiro número aqui: '))
numero_1 = int(input('Digite o segundo número aqui: '))
numero_2 = int(input('Digite o terceiro número aqui: '))
lista_numeros = [numero, numero_1, numero_2]
```

Gostaria de transformar esses 3 input's em um só.

Ex:

```
numeros = int(input('Digite os números aqui: '))
lista_numeros = [numeros]
```

porém essa segunda execução dá erro de:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3 5'

Eu acredito que pode ser por causa dos espaços entre os números.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perceba que você deve fazer uma [checagem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4289557/5429980) antes para garantir que é um numero que esta vindo pela entrada, isto é feito pela função `isdigit()`.

Veja abaixo o exemplo:

```
numeros = [int(v) for v in input('Valores: ').split() if v.isdigit()]
print(numeros)
```

**Entrada**:

```
1 32 3 55
```

**Saída**:

> [1, 32, 3, 55]

A saída é uma lista de números inteiros que foram retornados separadamente por `int(v)` através da *list comprehension*, seguindo da condição especificada `isdigit(s)` que simplesmente verifica se o valor é um digito.

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@drmcarvalho/inputlist).

Comment: Muito obrigado, agora ficou bem claro para mim. Só uma duvida que tive aqui, esse 'v' que foi definido é somente uma variável qualquer podendo ser X , Y ou Z por exemplo ?

Comment: É sim, ela é criada no escopo da list comprehension e você pode dar o nome que quiser para a variável. Em uma notação em português: `valor para valor em variaveInteravel`

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado pela ajuda!!

Answer (score 0):

O que você pode fazer é capturar a linha de entrada, dividi-la em substrings nos espaços, e depois fazer o parse dos inteiros:

```
entrada = input('Digite os números aqui: ')
numeros = [int(i) for i in entrada.split(' ')]
```